# How to format text using CSS

Tags: css

I was wondering how can align my text so it will display the way I want it to. Can someone help me display the text like it is in example 2 using CSS?

Here is what my text is doing.

```
Name: At vero eos et 
accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos d
```

Here is what I want it do.

```
Name: At vero eos et 
      accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos d
```

HTML markup.

```
<div><p><span>Name:</span> At vero eos et 
      accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos d</p></div>
```

Comment: What is the HTML markup? CSS is not a text formatting language. What you want is possible, but depends greatly on the HTML markup.

Comment: can you re-mark-up your HTML? e.g. <div class="passage"><div class="name">Name:</div><div class="dialogue">At vero eos et <br />
accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos d</div></div>

Comment: assigning classes - useful if you use div and span for other uses than name/dialogue on the page. assuming that you will only have dialogue structured like above on the page, my answer below will format all div's and span's in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
div{
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  margin-left: 65px;
}
span{
  margin-left: -65px;
} 
</style>
```

Hopefully you can put a `<br />` at the end of each linebreak. If you have PHP, you can use `nl2br()`

You can see the results and code @ http://jsfiddle.net/Sghym/